# Using ADO.NET how to insert list of data into SQL?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a list off data like
`list=[{id:1,name:"ABC",age:12},{id:2,name:"QWE",age:21}]`
I want to insert these data into database dynamically.

I googled and found how to insert a particular data. but dont know how to read the list andthen nsert those data.

```
string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            string sql = null;
            connetionString = "Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=testDB;User ID=ABCD;Password=password";
            sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (id,name,age) VALUES('1','ABC',12)";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();;
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
```

Comment: oh well ... asking you upfront ... coding is not an issue in itself, isn't it?

Comment: For inserting and reading you should use different codes. For example you read data and maybe you show in griedview and maybe after a click event you can insert table some values. You wrote how can you insert if you want I can write you how can you read?

Comment: Your data, IMHO, is JSON so you could use a library to parse json to some class. Then you can use a prepared statement to insert every single record of that array...

Comment: Check this blog. It has answers on your questions 
https://grauenwolf.github.io/DotNet-ORM-Cookbook/Joins.htm#ado.net
https://grauenwolf.github.io/DotNet-ORM-Cookbook/MultipleCrud.htm#ado.net

Comment: Use bulk insert.                                                                                               SqlBulkCopy

Answer (score 0):

```
cnx.Open(); // open cnx 
if(List.Count !=0){ // if List isn't empty 
    for(int i = 0 i < List.Count ;i++)
        {
            // here he will execute one by one 
            string myQuery ="insert into TABLE_NAME values ('"+List[i][0]+"','"+List[i][1]+"','"+List[i][3]+"' ");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery,cnx);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
// i hope it's help you :))
```

Comment: and that's how you get a SQL injection attack; sorry, but this is a bad answer IMO - anything that promotes concatenating inputs to create SQL is inherently **extremely** bad

Comment: So what is the best way ? :)) ?

Comment: parameterized SQL, or if you're doing a lot of rows: `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: aha i see Thanks